# CD/DVD-ROM - Media "unreadable"

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd

My DVD-RW drive has stopped working, all of a sudden.

I am using an HP CDDVDW SH-216BB on Windows 8.1 to read a CD (Which, by the way, is totally readable in another computer), but it doesn't work. It still shows that the drive is there, it just thinks that the drive is empty.

I have tried Microsoft's Fixit program (came back with a "media unreadable" error), disabling the drive, uninstalling the drive through Device Manager, and basically anything I can get my hands on, but to no avail.

I've tried the regedit (deleting upper and lower filters from the HKEY local machine), but when I navigate to the folder, there is no `UpperFilter` or `LowerFilter`. I'm quite sure I have the correct folder, too.

What is going on? Does this mean that I need to replace the drive? All the BIOS boot menus and the device properties say that the drive is connected properly. Plus, the driver is up to date.

I'm really frustrated at this, and would love some help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Optical drives fail. Purchase a new one. End of story. Also, when you cite the steps you've taken provide a little more detail and links when possible. Not everyone reading your question will be familiar with the particular Fixit or registry modification that you're referring to.

Comment: I feel like that shouldn't be the case... I've had this computer for about a year (bought new), and have used the drive fairly regularly. Do you know any other reason why this would happen?